# Angular 5 Master/Detail routing best practise

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am just learning Angular 5 and I stuck on Master/Detail best practise. In Angular official tutorial is Master/Detail section (here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3) with following pattern:

- Master component (which contains **list** of Heroes)

  - Detail component used within master (which is **detail** of selected Hero)

This sample operates without Route configuration, so no change in URL during Hero selection. Whole logic is operated within Master component.

A step later there is a Router section (here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)

Routing sample uses both List and Detail components in routing on same level and both operates separately with its own logic.

My question #1:

Is it OK with any Angular convention to combine this two samples. My purpose is to create HeroesContainer which contains two components - Heroes List and Hero Detail.

- Heroes Container component

  - Heroes List (which contains **list** of Heroes)
  - Hero Detail component (which is **detail** of selected Hero)

Router is then set to:

```
{
  path: 'heroes',
  component: HeroesContainerComponent,
}, {
  path: 'heroes/:id',
  component: HeroesContainerComponent,
}
```

And then if NO id is routed, then HeroDetailComponent is hidden.

If ANY id is routed, HeroesListComponent is hidden.

My question #2:

Will Angular preserve state of component when navigating to same component? Use case: User perform sorting & filtering on the list, open some Hero (navigate to detail), and then hit 'Back button'. I used pattern described above in AngularJS to achive this.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I dont think is a good approach to mix the responsibilities of two different views into one component only for the sake of preserving some state values (in the case that angular does what you think). There are other ways to archive persistence of state, for example services.

Comment: No, Angular won't preserve the state. A new component instance will be created when navigating to a different route. I completely agree with Jota here. Adhere to the single-responsibility principle. And of course a route dedicated to a here is much cleaner: you generally want to be able to link to a specific hero, not just to the list of heroes.

Comment: From my point of view there is a clear separation - separate component for list and for detail. But if Angular does not handle state that way, there is no need to have the third, a container component. Route directly to List and Detail component is much cleaner then